# How are Java Lock Conditions Initialized

Tags: java

The following code is an example right out of the Oracle java documentation.

```
 class BoundedBuffer {
   final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
   final Condition notFull  = lock.newCondition(); 
   final Condition notEmpty = lock.newCondition(); 

   final Object[] items = new Object[100];
   int putptr, takeptr, count;

   public void put(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == items.length) 
         notFull.await();
       items[putptr] = x; 
       if (++putptr == items.length) putptr = 0;
       ++count;
       notEmpty.signal();
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   }

   public Object take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lock();
     try {
       while (count == 0) 
         notEmpty.await();
       Object x = items[takeptr]; 
       if (++takeptr == items.length) takeptr = 0;
       --count;
       notFull.signal();
       return x;
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
   } 
 }
```

I can see how get() and take() handshake through notFull and notEmpty.  What I cannot find is how notFull, notEmpty, and count are initialized.  Where would Empty be set, full be cleared and count zeroed?  You an create other conditions, but I don't see where they are initialized either.   Shouldn't this happen in the constructor?

Comment: I don't see definitions for `Empty` and `full`.  `count` is an `int`, so presumably it's set to 0 when the object is instantiated.  The calls to `lock.newCondition()` set the initial states for `notFull` and `notEmpty`.

Comment: Since count is just an integer, doesn't it have to be initialized within the class before it is referenced?  Why doesn't it complain that the variable is not initialized?

Comment: Not the class `Integer`, the primitive type `int`.  Primitive types are automatically initialized to their default values.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: That makes it work.  Thank you.   Too simple (once you get it)

Comment: `Fields` are automatically initialized. Primitive fields to their default values and object type fields with `null`. Local variables for example are *not* automatically initialized - neither primitive nor object type.

Comment: Problem does not relate to the title.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Robert Harvey.  The int count defaults to 0.  That makes it work.